# The method 'getString' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: getString("UserType")

Tags: flutter, dart

I created Global SharedPreffrence inside my flutter app first It works fine but when I close the app and reopen again I face this Error.

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building HomePage(dirty, state: _HomePageState#1e763):
    The method 'getString' was called on null.
    Receiver: null
    Tried calling: getString("UserType")
```

---

```
Here is SharedPreference service class

import 'dart:async' show Future;
    import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

    class PreferenceUtils {
      static Future<SharedPreferences> get _instance async => _prefsInstance ??= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      static SharedPreferences _prefsInstance;

      // call this method from iniState() function of mainApp().
      static Future<SharedPreferences> init() async {
        _prefsInstance = await _instance;
        return _prefsInstance;
      }

      static String getString(String key, [String defValue]) {
        return _prefsInstance.getString(key) ?? defValue ?? "";
      }

      static Future<bool> setString(String key, String value) async {
        var prefs = await _instance;
        return prefs?.setString(key, value) ?? Future.value(false);
      }
    }
```

---

```
I Initialize this class from my initState() of main class

class _MyappState extends State<Myapp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    PreferenceUtils.init();
  }
```

---

```
Here is how I insert value to SharedPreference Key 

    PreferenceUtils.setString("UserType", ownerSnapshot.data()['Account type'].toString());
    PreferenceUtils.setString("UserId",workerSnapshot.data()['userId'].toString());
```

---

Here is Where I actually trying to use These SharedPreference i call getString('UserType')
in order to get the value of UserType from SharedPreference,

```
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        String UserTypes = PreferenceUtils.getString("UserType");

      if(isSignedIn){
     if(UserTypes=='owner'){
       return buildagentScreen();
    
     } else if(UserTypes== 'Seller'){
       return buildHomeScreen();
         }else{
       return buildSignedInScreen();
     }
    
      }
      }
```

Here is The Error I get when I'm trying to reopen the app agin

```
 The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building HomePage(dirty, state: _HomePageState#1e763):
    The method 'getString' was called on null.
    Receiver: null
    Tried calling: getString("UserType")
    
    The relevant error-causing widget was: 
      HomePage HomePage:file:///C:/Users/likec/OneDrive/Desktop/project%20file/nethouese/lib/main.dart:61:29
    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
    #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:63:5)
    #1      PreferenceUtils.getString (package:nethouese/pages/imported/pages/SharedPreferences.dart:15:27)
    #2      _HomePageState.build (package:nethouese/pages/imported/pages/HomePage.dart:70:40)
    #3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4775:27)
```

Comment: You are not calling `await` on `PreferenceUtils.init();` so there is no guarantee `_prefsInstance` is being initialized before calling `getString` on it.

Comment: Also `_prefsInstance.getString(key) ?? defValue ?? "";` is not null safe in the event that `_prefsInstance` has not been initialized yet. You could do `"_prefsInstance?.getString(key) ?? defValue ?? "";` to use the default value in the case where `_prefsInstance` is not yet initialized.

Comment: Thank you,  So IS It Possible to add await keyword inside initState(). how can I achieve that

Comment: @override
  Future<void> initState() async {
    super.initState();
    await PreferenceUtils.init();
  }, is it possible to add await keyword like this

Comment: I don't believe so, you would be changing the signature of the `initState` function. I don't think you can `await` directly inside of `initState`. Instead you could try moving your initialization up to your main method, which can be `Future<void> main() async {...}`.

Comment: Could you please correct my code! i don't clearly understand the problem,main.dart file is available above

Comment: try  `Future<void> main() async { await PreferenceUtils.init(); runApp(MyApp()); }` instead of calling `PreferenceUtils.init()` inside of `initState`.

Comment: OK Thank You Brother, you are Smart